# Batch Apex to add 10 Days to Closed date and then Automatically Change the Stage Name to CLOSED WON/LOST after 10 days

Tags: schedulebatch

```
public class oppstage implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    public Database.QueryLocator start (Database.BatchableContext bc){
        return database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id FROM Opportunity');
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Opportunity> records){
        list<Opportunity> updatedopp = new list<Opportunity>();
        for(Opportunity obj:records){
            if(obj.extra__c == date.today()){
                obj.stagename= 'Closed Won';
                updatedopp.add(obj);
            }
        }

        if(!updatedopp.isEmpty()){
            update updatedopp;
        }
    }
    
    public void finish (Database.BatchableContext BC){
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now, there is no question here. You have a statement (in your title) and a code dump. You need to use words to explain what your problem is, what you've tried so far to solve the problem, and point to a specific place where you're stuck. [Edit] your question to add that information.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have updated your code. I have just added the  `WHERE CloseDate < N_DAYS_AGO:10'` in the query which is filtered the data which is processed into the batch.

Here is the full code:

```
public class oppstage implements Database.Batchable { 

    public Database.QueryLocator start (Database.BatchableContext bc){ 
        return database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE CloseDate < N_DAYS_AGO:10'); 
    } 

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List records){ 
        List updatedopp = new List(); 
        for(Opportunity obj : records){ 
            if(obj.extra__c == date.today()){ 
                obj.StageName= 'Closed Won'; 
                updatedopp.add(obj);
            }
        }
        if(updatedopp.size() > 0){
            update updatedopp;
        }
    }

    public void finish (Database.BatchableContext BC){}
}
```

Reference for the N_DAYS_AGO : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

Comment: I don't think this sufficiently answers the question (or, well, the _implied_ question since there isn't much in the way of a question at the moment). Without further clarification, I assume that the ask here is mainly "how to automatically update after x time". In that regard, your suggested code is not sufficient. On its own, this code would let records sit potentially indefinitely (and it appears that the comparison operator is wrong). The point I'm making here is that this is not _automatic_, _something_ would need to call this code.

Comment: This is also an example of a question that should not be answered. See the "Answer well-asked questions" section of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer. This question is lacking in detail, and feels like a "do my work for me" type of "question".